Regional settings impacting csv file
I have a macro that saves an Excel sheet with a range as a separate file in CSV MS-DOS format. It worked well until I changed regional settings to non-US (specifically to Poland for example with date format dd.mm.yyyy and list separator ; ). After that change, the final CSV file presents data in one column, with data separated by commas, not in a nice range format, with data presented in each column, as I had it before saving the sheet as csv.
I tried to change a list separator in Windows setting from ; to , and the other way around, but it didn't help.
Could you please advise how to make the macro work?
The code I have is as follows:
Dim MyWB As Workbook
Dim wbkOut As Workbook
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet

Set MyWB = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSrc = MyWB.Sheets(2)
Set wbkOut = Workbooks.Add
Set wsOut = wbkOut.Sheets(1)

wsSrc.Copy wsOut
wsOut.Delete
wbkOut.SaveAs "C:\Users\Downloads\testfile.csv", xlCSVMSDOS
wbkOut.Close False
Set wbkOut = Nothing
Set wsOut = Nothing
Set wsSrc = Nothing


The macro probably works fine. If using Excel to view CSV files, safest is to import (not open) the file, specifying the delimiter.

Or better still, only open them in a text editor to verify ;)

As many columns does the csv file have? Do you need different format for each column?

Please, use the next way to open the respective csv file (created with your code):
Private Sub openAsTextTextFormat()
 Dim fileToOpen As Variant, arrTxt, nrCol As Long, arr(), i As Long
 Dim OpenBook As Workbook

 fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv")


 If fileToOpen <> False Then
    'Check the number of text file columns:
    arrTxt = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(fileToOpen, 1).ReadAll, vbLf)
    nrCol = UBound(Split(arrTxt(0), vbTab))
    '______________________________________
    ReDim arr(nrCol) 'redim the format array
    For i = 0 To nrCol
        Select Case i
            Case 1
                arr(i) = Array(1, 4) ' Date format (DMY)
            Case 3, 4
                arr(i) = Array(1, 2) 'fill the format array with variant for TEXT Format!
            Case Else
                arr(i) = Array(1, 1) 'General format
        End Select
    Next
    ' the necessary constants from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcolumndatatype

    Workbooks.OpenText fileName:=fileToOpen, origin:=932, startRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        Other:=True, OtherChar:="|", InfoField:=arr()
    Set OpenBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Stop ' The code will stop here! Please, check if the text file has been open with the correct format. Then, press F5...
      'do whatever you need with the file (or change the format in arr())
    OpenBook.Close False
 End If
End Sub

Check the format of each column and adapt arr() according to your needs, looking to the constants description here.
Your existing code can be easily adapted to be more compact:
Dim MyWB As Workbook, wbkOut As Workbook

Set MyWB = ThisWorkbook
MyWB.Sheets(2).Copy 'it creates a new workbook with that sheet content
Set wbkOut = ActiveWorkbook 'the newly created workbok...

wbkOut.SaveAs "C:\Users\Downloads\testfile.csv", xlCSVMSDOS
wbkOut.Close False

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Had macro that was used in 5 different countries - same company.
Dealt with this by having a subroutine in the macro that would collect the settings from the local machine and use those to process the results, chart settings (months etc).
The data was obviously the same but the chart titles, axes and also headings were set in each language.
Also had the help texts chosen for the language needed - (French, Italian, German etc).
Used lookup(), choose(), index() with match() once the texts were sorted.
